# Javascript Passing Object into Object Method

Tags: javascript, html, object, methods, undefined

As the title suggests, I am trying to pass an object into an object method in Javascript. To be more precise I am trying to implement vector objects into a simple physics engine I need to create, and I want to add a function in my vector object that will add another vector to it. Sadly when I try to do so, in the method the parameter that stores the vector keeps saying it is undefined. Can you please tell me why it is undefined and how to fix it? I have searched all over and cannot find anything that addresses my particular problem. Here is my code:

```
function launch() {

running = false;

var payloadMass = 5291.7; // For SES-10 (kg)
var fairingMass = 2000; // (kg)

var time = 0;
var seconds = 0;
var minutes = 0;
var hours = 0;

var massFirstF = 438200; // (kg)
var massFirstE = 27200; // (kg)
var thrustFirst = 7607; // (kN)
var thrustFirstVac = 8227; // (kN)
var timeFirst = 162; // (sec) [162]

var massSecondF = 116000; // (kg)
var massSecondE = 4500; // (kg)
var thrustSecond = 934; // (kN)
var timeSecond = 397; // (sec)

//var gravity = 9.81; // (m/s^2)
var gravity = new vector2(0, -9.81);

var fuelFirst = 411000; // (kg) [411000]
var fuelFirstF = 411000; // (kg) [411000]
var fuelSecond = 111500; // (kg)
var fuelSecondF = 111500; // (kg)
var fuelFlowFirst = fuelFirst / timeFirst; // (kg/s)
var fuelFlowSecond = fuelSecond / timeSecond; // (kg/s)

var fuel = fuelFirst; // (kg)
var full = fuelFirstF; // (kg)

var stage = 0; // 0=First 1=Second 2=Payload
//var altitude = 0; // (m)
var velocity = 0; // (m/s)
//var acceleration = 0; // (m/s^2)
var acceleration = new vector2(0, 0);
//var accelDiff = acceleration - gravity; // (m/s^2)
var accelDiff = new vector2(0, acceleration - gravity.y);
var mass = massFirstF + massSecondF + payloadMass + fairingMass; // (kg)

var tempTime = 0;

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = canvas.scrollWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.scrollHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = "15px Arial";

var start = new buttonC(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 100, 100 , "blue");

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);

if (isInside(mousePos, start)) {
    running = !running;
}else{

}   
}, false);

start.draw(ctx);

var spacexImg = new Image();
spacexImg.src="http://www.spacex.com/sites/all/themes/spacex2012/images/falcon9/falcon9-render.png";
spacexImg.width = spacexImg.width / 20;
spacexImg.height = spacexImg.height / 20;
var plumeImg = new Image();
plumeImg.src="plume.jpg";

plumeImg.height = (plumeImg.width / spacexImg.width) * plumeImg.height;
plumeImg.width = spacexImg.width;

var falcon = new rocket(spacexImg, (canvas.width / 2) - (spacexImg.width / 2), (canvas.height ) - (spacexImg.height));

setInterval(function(){
    if (running){
        if (stage == 0){
            fuelFirst = fuelFirst - (fuelFlowFirst * 0.01);
            mass = (massFirstE + fuelFirst) + massSecondF + payloadMass + fairingMass;
            acceleration.y = ((thrustFirst * 1000) / (mass));
            fuel = fuelFirst;
            full = fuelFirstF;
        if (fuel <= 0){
            stage = 1;
            tempTime = time;
        }
    }
    if (stage == 1){
        if (time <= (tempTime + 5)){
            acceleration.x = 0;
            acceleration.y = 0;
        }
        else{
            fuelSecond = fuelSecond - (fuelFlowSecond * 0.01);
            mass = (massSecondE + fuelSecond) + payloadMass + fairingMass;
            acceleration.y = ((thrustSecond * 1000) / (mass));
            fuel = fuelSecond;
            full = fuelSecondF;
            if (fuel <= 0){
                stage = 2;
                tempTime = time;
                acceleration.x = 0;
                acceleration.y = 0;
                fuel = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    //accelDiff = acceleration - gravity;
    accelDiff.add(acceleration.sub(gravity, 1), 1);
    falcon.vel.add(accelDiff, 0.01);
    //velocity = velocity + (accelDiff * 0.01);
    falcon.loc.add(velocity, 0.01);

    time = time + 0.01;
    minutes = truncateDecimals((time / 60) - (hours * 60), 0);
    seconds = truncateDecimals(time - ((minutes * 60) + (hours * 3600)), 0);
    hours = truncateDecimals((time / 60) / 60, 0);


    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText("Time = " + truncateDecimals(time, 0)
           + " sec. Or: " + hours + 
             " hours, " + minutes + 
             " minutes, " + seconds + 
             " seconds.", 10, 30)
    ctx.fillText("Altitude: " + truncateDecimals(falcon.loc.y, 2) + " meters", 10, 45);
    ctx.fillText("Acceleration: " + truncateDecimals(accelDiff, 2) + " m/s^2", 10, 60)
    ctx.fillText("Velocity: " + truncateDecimals(velocity, 2) + " m/s", 10, 75);
    ctx.fillText("Mass: " + truncateDecimals(mass, 2) + " kg", 10, 90);
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillText("Fuel: ", 10, 105);
    ctx.fillRect(10, 120, 50, 104);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(10, 122 + (100 - ((fuel / full) * 100)));
    ctx.lineTo(70, 122 + (100 - ((fuel / full) * 100)));
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillText(truncateDecimals((fuel / full) * 100, 1) + "%", 70, 122 + (100 - ((fuel / full) * 100)));
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.fillRect(15, 122 + (100 - ((fuel / full) * 100)), 40, ((fuel / full) * 100));
    //falcon.loc.y = (canvas.height - spacexImg.height) - falcon.loc.y;
    falcon.draw(ctx);
    if (acceleration > 0){
        ctx.drawImage(plumeImg, falcon.loc.x , falcon.loc.y + spacexImg.height, plumeImg.width, plumeImg.height);   
    }
}
}, 10);
};

//Function to check whether a point is inside a rectangle
function isInside(pos, buttonC){
    return pos.x > buttonC.x && pos.x < buttonC.x+buttonC.width && pos.y < buttonC.y+buttonC.height && pos.y > buttonC.y;
}

function buttonC(x, y, width, height, color){
    this.x = x - (width / 2);
    this.y = y - (height / 2);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.color = color;
    this.draw = function (ctx){
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, width, height);
    };
}

function getMousePos(canvas, event) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
    x: event.clientX - rect.left,
    y: event.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

truncateDecimals = function (number, digits) {
    var multiplier = Math.pow(10, digits),
    adjustedNum = number * multiplier,
    truncatedNum = Math[adjustedNum < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](adjustedNum);

    return truncatedNum / multiplier;
};

function vector2(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.add = function (vect, multiplier){
        this.x = this.x + (vect.x * multiplier);
        this.y = this.y + (vect.y * multiplier);
    this.sub = function (vect, multiplier){
        this.x = this.x - (vect.x * multiplier);
        this.y = this.y - (vect.y * multiplier);
    };
}

function rocket(img, x, y) {
    this.img = img;
    this.loc = new vector2(x, y);
    this.vel = new vector2(0, 0);
    this.draw = function(ctx) {
        ctx.drawImage(img, this.loc.x, this.loc.y, img.width, img.height);
    }
};
```

Comment: How do you call that function and method?

Comment: `this` depends on the execution context, not how it's defined.

Comment: This is just the only relevant portion, I could give you all of it but it would behave exactly the same as if you just put that into a file by itself.

Comment: No, if I run this code nothing happens. We need code that produces the error. Not the whole script, just a sample call to illustrate the error you get.

Comment: Alright I will at it right now.

Comment: Figure that might help a little bit now?

Comment: Too much code, most of it is unrelated to the problem.  A better example would be similar to what @RobM has posted in his answer.

Comment: PS your code is missing a close brace (`}`) after the definition of vector2.add.

Comment: Except that works, mine doesn't, I can take out some things but then other things will not work, it is old code I am trying to rework. Also the code brace is there it just isn't showing up here when I paste it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that you are using the `new` keyword (`var vector = new vector2()`) when calling `vector2`, otherwise your reference to `this` will point to something other than your function (probably `window` if you are running in the browser):

```js
function vector2(x, y) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.add = function (vect, multiplier){
      this.x = this.x + (vect.x * multiplier);
      this.y = this.y + (vect.y * multiplier);
   };
}

var vec1 = new vector2(10, 10);
var vec2 = new vector2(20, 20);
vec1.add(vec2, 5);

console.log(vec1.x, vec1.y);
```

After looking at your edit with the full source, your code is expecting that `.add` and `.sub` return the instance

```
// .add expects a vector, .sub does not return a vector
accelDiff.add(acceleration.sub(gravity, 1), 1);
```

and those methods do not have a return statement (so they return `undefined`). Try this:

```
this.add = function (vect, multiplier){
    this.x = this.x + (vect.x * multiplier);
    this.y = this.y + (vect.y * multiplier);
    return this;
};
this.sub = function (vect, multiplier){
    this.x = this.x - (vect.x * multiplier);
    this.y = this.y - (vect.y * multiplier);
    return this;
};
```

Comment: I have been using the new keyword though, as you can see now.

Comment: It works now!! Thank you so much, I am just wondering, where does my code expect that? It would be very helpful then I can mark yours as the correct answer.

Comment: Found it - `accelDiff.add(acceleration.sub(gravity, 1), 1);` - the return value from .sub has to be a vector for the .add to work.

Comment: @James yep, that's the one! I updated my answer with the problematic line

Comment: @user140052 My pleasure, glad it's working for you now! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This line has a problem:

```
accelDiff.add(acceleration.sub(gravity, 1), 1);
```

The call to `sub` does not return a value, so you pass `undefined` as first argument to `add`.

So you should really separate the calls, like this:

```
acceleration.sub(gravity, 1);
accelDiff.add(gravity, 1);
```

One nice way to solve this, is to let your vector methods return `this`:

```
function vector2(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.add = function (vect, multiplier){
        this.x = this.x + (vect.x * multiplier);
        this.y = this.y + (vect.y * multiplier);
        return this; // <----
    this.sub = function (vect, multiplier){
        this.x = this.x - (vect.x * multiplier);
        this.y = this.y - (vect.y * multiplier);
        return this; // <----
    };
}
```

With that change, you *can* write:

```
accelDiff.add(acceleration.sub(gravity, 1), 1);
```